# 3D wheel spinning effect in css

Tags: javascript, html, css, translation

I am trying to build a simple web element that resembles the wheel contestants spin on The Price is Right ([sample video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6mK5QvYqLrQ)). My question is: is there a more efficient way to achieve this effect than what I've cobbled together below?

My first attempt at this functionality basically decrements the `translateY` property of an element that contains the elements to be spun [[codepen]](https://codepen.io/duhaime/pen/OOmEJN):

```js
setInterval(shiftCards, 100)

var translateY = -60,
    cardIdx = 0,
    startCards = 60,
    wrap = document.querySelector('.wrap');

for (var i=0; i<startCards; i++) {
  addCard()
}

function addCard() {
  var div = document.createElement('div');
  div.className = 'card';
  div.style.top = (cardIdx * 12) + 'px';
  wrap.appendChild(div);
  cardIdx++;
}

function shiftCards() {
  wrap.style.transform = 'translateY(' + translateY + 'px)';
  translateY -= 12;
  var cards = wrap.querySelectorAll('.card');
  if (cards.length >= startCards) {
    cards[0].parentNode.removeChild(cards[0]);
    addCard();
  }
}
```

```css
.cards {
  width: 80px;
  height: 200px;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: #aaa;
}

.wrap {
  position: relative;
  transition: transform .25s;
}

.card {
  width: 100%;
  height: 10px;
  margin: 2px 0;
  background: red;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class='cards'>
   <div class='wrap'>
  </div>
</div>
```

Is there a more efficient way to achieve this functionality? Can I create an element with n children and actually just spin them in the Z-dimension, rather than create an artificial spin as I've done above? Any guidance others can offer on this question will be very appreciated!

Comment: Have you had a look at http://desandro.github.io/3dtransforms/examples/carousel-02-dynamic.html

Comment: @klugjo I hadn't seen it, but this is PERFECT. Thanks very much for the reference!

Comment: @klugjo If you make your response an answer I'll accept it--this really is grand

Answer (score 1):

You can use css-animations for this: (They are probably more efficient)

```css
/* only alignment */
body, html {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.wrapper {
  display:flex;
  justify-content:center;
  align-items:center;
  height: 100%;
}

/* actual spinning */
img {
  animation: spin 5s infinite linear;
  /*
    spin:   the keyframes (=animation) we want to have
    5s:     how long it should take for one iteration
    infinite: how often should it repeat
    linear: the easing between the different key frames You can also try 'ease'
  */
}


@keyframes spin {
    0%   {transform: translateY(-60px);}    /* Starting point */
    100% {transform: translateY(-360px);}  /* end point */
}

@-webkit-keyframes spin {
    0%   {transform: translateY(-60px);}
    100% {transform: translateY(-360px);}
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <img src="https://www.placecage.com/300/100" class="spin">
</div>
```

Comment: I am sorry. I paused between watching the video and posting the answer, so i forgot about it. It still kinda works (I have updated it with the same transformation that you had), but probably not what you are searching for. I will still keep it up for reference.